# Not showing data in dridview

Tags: c#-4.0, datagridview

[image: Snapshot of error]

Why this error occur my datasource is not null.
Please give some suggestions.

Comment: `dataGridView1` is null.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta but i assign a datasource to it why this is null....

Comment: Well, you haven't assigned a datasource to it *yet*. Do you ever assign a value to `dataGridView1`, after you declare that variable?

Comment: Yes i assign a datasource named "tempBill" which is a list.

Comment: you haven't initialized `dataGridView1`, you probably added it in the code, or make sure you are not doing `dataGridView1 = null` in your code anywhere

Comment: @Habib ya i am not doing dataGridView1 = null any where

Comment: @MohdWaseem, then make sure you instantiate your `dataGridView1` in your code like `dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();`, if you added the gridview from your code, not in design

Comment: @Habib thanks the problem is solved..

Answer (score 0):

Where did you call GetGrid()? Did it call it before InitializeComponent(); It must be called after InitializeComponent();